# Audio is out of sync with Avconv

Tags: avconv, audio-sync

I'm broadcasting to Justin TV with this script found [on Github](https://gist.github.com/brodul/3178130) on Ubuntu 12.04.

I am having issues with the audio going out of sync and getting worse as I go through my playlist.

This is the code I'm using for avconv. And I can't figure out how to set the bitrate for the audio. I've seen `-b` as bandwidth but it looks like it should be the audio bitrate.

How to resolve this ?

```
avconv \
  -f x11grab -s $INRES  -r "$FPS" -i :0.0 \
  -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse  \
  -vcodec libx264 -s $OUTRES -preset $QUAL \
  -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 4 -qscale 3 -b:a 98304  -bufsize 512k \
  -f flv "rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

make sure it contains these lines (adding or uncommenting)

default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 44100

Comment: it had an alternative of 48000

Comment: nothing changed btw the audio is way ahead